# Integrating S Health SDK

Tags: android

I have developed my app using Samsung S Health SDK. I want to add walking, running and cycling tracking of S Health inside my app.

How to add these features?

Comment: can you guide me how to develop sample app using S health SDK. if you have any example please share it with me

Comment: @saikrupa exactly what data you need? they have given sample apps in docs, you can refer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added following properties inside my readTodayWalkingDistance():

```
private void readTodayWalkingDistance() {
    HealthDataResolver resolver = new HealthDataResolver(mStore, null);

    // Set time range from start time of today to the current time
    long startTime = getStartTimeOfToday();
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Filter filter = Filter.and(Filter.greaterThanEquals(HealthConstants.Exercise.START_TIME, startTime),
            Filter.lessThanEquals(HealthConstants.Exercise.START_TIME, endTime));

    HealthDataResolver.ReadRequest request = new ReadRequest.Builder()
            .setDataType(HealthConstants.Exercise.HEALTH_DATA_TYPE)
            .setProperties(new String[]{
                    HealthConstants.Exercise.EXERCISE_TYPE,
                    HealthConstants.Exercise.DURATION,
                    HealthConstants.Exercise.MAX_SPEED,
                    HealthConstants.Exercise.MEAN_SPEED,
            })
            .setFilter(filter)
            .build();

    try {
        resolver.read(request).setResultListener(mListener);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(MainActivity.APP_TAG, e.getClass().getName() + " - " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Then updated ResultListener:

```
private final HealthResultHolder.ResultListener<ReadResult> mListener = new HealthResultHolder.ResultListener<ReadResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(ReadResult result) {
        int exercise_type = 0;
        long duration = 0;
        float max_speed = 0.0f, mean_speed = 0.0f;
        Cursor c = null;

        try {
            c = result.getResultCursor();
            if (c != null) {
                while (c.moveToNext()) {

                    exercise_type += c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(HealthConstants.Exercise.EXERCISE_TYPE));
                    duration += c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(HealthConstants.Exercise.DURATION));
                    max_speed += c.getColumnIndex(HealthConstants.Exercise.MAX_SPEED);
                    mean_speed += c.getColumnIndex(HealthConstants.Exercise.MEAN_SPEED);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                c.close();
            }
        }
        MainActivity.getInstance().getData(exercise_type, duration, max_speed, mean_speed);
    }
};
```

Added following permissions in to HashSet MainActivity:

```
mKeySet.add(new PermissionKey(HealthConstants.Exercise.HEALTH_DATA_TYPE, PermissionType.READ));
```

And in AndroidManifest file:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.samsung.android.health.permission.read"
    android:value="com.samsung.health.exercise" />
```

Comment: what did you use for it? Jar file or dependency ?

Comment: @AnshulTyagi I used **samsung-digital-health-healthdata-1.2.1.jar** file

Comment: ok. Can you please provide me lil source code or idea how it reads data of S health app for running exercise etc ?

Comment: @Shruti how we can fetch all total active mint of day from Samsung health sdk

Comment: @wadali is it possible with Samsung Health? I have a doubt

Comment: @Shruti Yes from Samsung health

Comment: @Shruti Very helpful -Vote up! ;)

Comment: Hey. How can we get the exercise name? I found a link with different types if activities here http://developer.samsung.com/onlinedocs/health/EXERCISE_TYPE.html . But is there any way to get to know the activity name in the app itself?

Comment: @Anu Nope, we can't get the Exercise name; we can only get its ID(EXERCISE_TYPE) and can compare from that.

Comment: Hi shruthi can you please give me link to download samsung-digital-health-healthdata-1.2.1.jar